# What's the proper way to handle error result in promise object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Say there's a promise object:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(body);
                }
            });
        });
```

There's an error property in the callback, I can use `reject()` to handle it. But with the body, I can get either `{ok: 1}` or `{ok: -1}`. So how should I handle this error result?

I think I can just `resolve()` the `body`, and check the result in `then()`. Or I should check the result immediately and put the bad result into `reject()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An error in your body should be considered what it is - an error -, and thus reject. Although ideally the server should return an error status code.Here's what I would do if you can't modify the server:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else if (body.ok === -1) {
                reject(new Error('error'));
            else {
                resolve(body);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Oh yes, the server does return an error code and a error message. I just use ok as a sample. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. And if I need to send response to browser, with the error message should I send it with `status(200)` or `status(500)`? Could you give me some advices?

Comment: Error codes have a meaning. Send a 400 if a parameter is missing, 404 if the resource is not found, 403 if user needs special (e.g. admin) rights, etc. Browse this list and pick the one most appropriate for each case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you probably don't need to pass on the body as such, but rather the interpretation of whether the command succeeded or not. So try this

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            request.post(options, (err, res, body) => {
                if(err) {
                    return reject(err);
                } 
                if (body.ok == -1) return reject('bad news');

                return resolve('good news');

            });
        });
```

and then you use this as:

```
funcAboveThatReturnsPromise()
.then( () => res.sendStatus(200).end() )
.catch( err => res.sendStatus(500).send(err) )
```

Comment: Thanks. And if I need to send response to browser, with the error message should I send it with `status(200)` or `status(500)`? Could you give me some advices?

Comment: You should ideally ask a new question for this, but I have updated my answer